# DELETE FROM t1 WHERE multiple fields equal to SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I am attempting to delete several records within a table WHERE three (3) of those fields equal to a SELECT FROM the same table MINUS three (3) fields from another table.
Just executing the SELECT statement, I get the correct number of records.

Just to verify the number of records I am looking for, I've created the following query:

```
  SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
  FROM t2
```

It returns the correct number of records I'm expecting.
When I run the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE (c1, c2, c3) IN (
  SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
  FROM t2)
;
```

I receive more than five (5) times the amount of records. Most of which I do not want to delete.

The target code is something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM t1
WHERE (c1, c2, c3) IN (
  SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
  FROM t2)
;
```

Delete all of the records in table 1 based on the next query:

```
  SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
  FROM t2
```

Comment: `MINUS` removes duplicates.  The discrepancy in the counts is probably due to duplicate values.

Comment: I couldn't see the question ...

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is, how do I delete all of the records from table 1 based on the query   SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
  FROM t2

Comment: Maybe some more context would help. I am attempting to clean up the data in t1. It has thousands of records that are no longer needed and/or errant. The records in t2 are accurate and a list of all valid data. I am attempting to delete all of the records in t1 that don’t match t2. All of the data in the c1, c2, and c3 columns match exactly, although both tables are not exact copies of each other.
If the records match in both tables, I want to keep those records in t1. If the records in t1 don’t match in t2, I want to delete those records.
Thank you for your help!